# Not able to get shipping details on custom page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, uicomponent, shipping-address

The below code I have created a custom step at checkout. I wanted to display the shipping information on it. I have written the code but it is not working.

```
<item name="order-summary" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string"><vendor>_ShoppingCart/js/view/summary</item>
    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">5</item>
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
         <item name="shipping-information" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-information</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress</item>
                </item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">shipping-information</item>
                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="ship-to" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-information/list</item>
                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">ship-to</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

I want this to appear on my custom step.
[image]

Comment: I think shipping step is available by default in Magento.

Comment: Why its not displaying on my custom step

Comment: Please update your question What actually you wanted to do ?

Comment: Ya done now check.

Comment: Oh I see, You wanted to move shipping Methods and shipping address block into new step. I thought you were just trying to create a new step.

You can refer to this. https://www.mageplaza.com/add-custom-checkout-step-magento-2.html

Comment: No no. I don't want to move shipping method and shipping address. I just want to display what was selected on shipping step.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76314/discussion-between-avesh-and-lazy-coder).